# Cannot read property 'HmacSHA256' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt an id so I can use as params in vue.js using crypto-js, but I keep getting this error. **Cannot read property 'HmacSHA256' of undefined** when I tried ASE and MD5 I had same error, What am I not doing right? this is my code

```
//in main.js
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
Vue.use(CryptoJS)

//im my component
goToEvent (singleEvent) {
  const id = this.CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(singleEvent.id, 'mySecreteKey').toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
  this.$store.commit('SET_SELECTED_EVENT', singleEvent)
  this.$router.push(`/admin/events/event/${id}`)
}
```

Comment: @Sphinx, that throws an error that **CryptoJS in not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your help, what I realized was that I had to pass my value to json string, I also had to add some few stuffs to get a value that is url friendly. this is my final solution

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

const key = 'mysecrete'



 // encryption
   export function Encrypt (text) {
    const b64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(text), key).toString()
      const e64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(b64)
      return e64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
    }
// decryption
export function Decrypt (text) {
  const reb64 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(text)
  const bytes = reb64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
  const decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(bytes, key)
  return decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
}
```

now I can import it in any component

Answer (score 1):

add `import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'` into your component file, then uses `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(...)` like below:

```
goToEvent (singleEvent) {
  const id = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(singleEvent.id, 'mySecreteKey').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
  this.$store.commit('SET_SELECTED_EVENT', singleEvent)
  this.$router.push(`/admin/events/event/${id}`)
}
```

**BTW**: `Vue.use(CryptoJS)` will not work because `'crypto-js'` is not a valid Vue plugin.

Or **another solution** is uses one valid Vue plugin named [Vue CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cryptojs), then in your single file component, you will be able to invoke `CryptoJS` instance by:

```
Vue.CryptoJS
this.CryptoJS
this.$CryptoJS
```